# Android - How do I set View.GONE outside the UI thread?

Tags: android, view, visibility, ui-thread

I want to make a view disappear (to be gone) when the user pushes a button.

I can make it inside the *onCreate()* method (main UI thread) by doing:

```
findViewById(R.id.llLoadingGallery).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

However, I want to be able to do the same thing inside another thread (out of the main UI thread). I tried to put the above live in my thread and it didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

**## EDIT ####**

To make myself more clear, I want to do something like this:

```
        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.teste_aba_3);

    botao_tab_musica.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ...
        findViewById(R.id.llLoadingGallery).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

}

However, that DOESN'T work! How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest either using View.post(Runnable), View.postDelayed(Runnable, long), a Handler, or an AsyncTask to do this for you.

There are some good examples on how to post to the UI thread in these scenarios:

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I don't want to actually start another thread. I want to change the UI (make that view gone) inside the onClick method of the button I have in my screen. How can I do that?

Comment: This is contrary what you said on your question - you said "out of the ui thread". Event handlers, e.g. `onClick()`, are always run on Ui thread.

Comment: Humm, so why is it that calling setVisibility(View.GONE); in the event handler doesn't work? I edited my question with some code.

Comment: You might want to post the contents of your teste_aba_3.xml layout file too because otherwise the code that you have should work.

Comment: I ran my application today and it worked... I have no idea what happened. I had cleaned, created another emulator, tested in a new device and everything, but it just didn't work yesterday. It worked now with the code I posted in my own question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

theres a neat method called `runOnUiThread`

```
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                findViewById(R.id.llLoadingGallery).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

edit: with your code

```
botao_tab_musica.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                findViewById(R.id.llLoadingGallery).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
}
```

});

Comment: Hi Michele. THanks for replying as well. But your solution also didn't work for me =( The view still remains intact! I can't get rid of this view! =(

Comment: Works great for me! Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

I think one possibility is to pass a reference to your activity to that other thread so that your thread can access the findViewById method.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
findViewById(R.id.llLoadingGallery).post(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
               findViewById(R.id.llLoadingGallery).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

or create AsyncTask